# Error ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection

Tags: plsql

Me podrían ayudar a saber cual es el problema con mi programa...
Tengo este código dentro de un paquete:

```
TYPE t_rec IS RECORD(t_id INTEGER,t_text VARCHAR2(40));
TYPE t_recs IS TABLE OF t_rec;

FUNCTION test_func RETURN tp_recs PIPELINED AS 
currec t_recs;
cur    t_rec;
reg number := 0;
BEGIN

for reg in 1..10 loop

  currec(reg).tt_id   := reg;
  currec(reg).tt_text := 'test '||reg;
end loop;

for reg in currec.first .. currec.last loop

  cur.tt_id   := currec(reg).tt_id;
  cur.tt_text := currec(reg).tt_text;

  pipe row(cur);
end loop;

END;
```

Cuando realizo un select sobre la función, me arroja el error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE( test_pkg.test_func());
```

> ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection

Comment: Los parametros son IN? Recibes una colección de t_recs? Porque en el primer loop estás mirando currec y no se ve dónde les estás poniendo datos

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas inicializar el objeto que estas regresando **tp_recs** antes de llenarlo con información.

Answer (score 0):

En ningún momento le pones datos a `currec`. Hasta donde lo tienes, es una variable del tipo TABLE OF del otro tipo. Pero no le has asignado ningún dato, entonces no hay nada por recorrer ni posiciones a consultar usando el índice `reg`